# Putting a circle with pm3d map

Tags: gnuplot

I made a density plot using pm3d map. The plot is
great (as expected) but now I need to put a circle (a circumference I mean) with centre at the origin and a given radius (three in my case).

I tried defining the function:
f(x)=sqrt(9.-x**2)
and adding to the plot:
splot 'file.dat' u 1:2:3 with pm3d, f(x),-f(x)
but the result is disastrous (as I suspected).
Is there any way to add a circle to the plot without distorting it ???

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `set object`:

```
set object circle at 0,0 size 1
plot x
```

[image]